# how can I efficiently apply an interpolation column wise

Tags: pandas

Let me first give you an idea what I would like to achieve in the end. I would like to have a class which has an attribute of type pandas core data frame. This data frame contains (x,y) value pairs which I would like to interpolate. An instance of the class will be mostly used to give me an interpolated value at a new point x.

Let me do an example

Having a pandas data frame

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import scipy
>>> x = np.arange(0,10)
>>> y1 = np.exp(-x/3.0)
>>> y2 = np.sqrt(x)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((y1[:,np.newaxis], y2[:,np.newaxis]),axis=1), index=x)
```

I would like to achieve an interpolation (either linear or cubic) column wise where the index is the x values for both columns. Preferred is a solution where the result is a function (the interpolator) per column.

This could be achieved via

```
>>> f = [scipy.interpolate.interp1d(df.index, df.iloc[:, i], kind='linear') for i in range(2)]
```

this gives me a list of interpolators. However, my final goal is that I have a class

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self._intep = [scipy.interpolate.interp1d(df.index,df.iloc[:, i], kind='linear') for i in range(len(df.columns))]  

    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        x, y = pos
        col = self.df.columns[y]
        l = [self._intep[i](x) for i in range(len(col))]
        return np.column_stack(l)
```

Using this I can nicely do something like

```
t = Test(df)
t[[1, 2, 4], :]
```

That's my ultimate goal. I want to access the class like a array and give me the desired values for specific columns. It should be really fast and optimized. Moreover, what if my columns have names? It seems then I need a dictionary instead of a list for the container of interpolators

Is this the right thing to do in python? I'm rather new to python and it feels a bit ugly to me :)

Comment: Can't you use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) / [`Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)?

Comment: @jdehesa thx for the answer. As far as I understood these methods interpolate the nan in the data frame. That means if I want a particular value I would need to add/insert a row in the data frame with nan. seems rather costly, no?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Then yes it's fine how you do it I'd say, although unless you have a huge number of columns and you usually only pick a few of them it'd probably be easier to interpolate everything and then filter the columns: `self._interp = interp1d(df.index, df, axis=0, kind='linear')`, then `self._interp(x)[y]`.

Comment: @jdehesa many thanks for the `interp(x)[y]`. That's indeed much nicer.

Comment: @jdehesa what dimension should `x` have? if I use the above example, i.e. `f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(df.index, df, kind="linear", axis=0)` and then `f(np.arange(0,9,0.01)[1]` I dont get the desired format back

Comment: Sorry, it should be `interp(x)[:, y]`

Comment: @jdehesa many thanks for you patience. But I have to stick to my current solution. Unfortunately the `fill_value` argument does not allowed to be different per column. I.e. I can't hand over a 2dim array there.